# Why does this equality imply that the inverse image is open?

Tags: general-topology

Question: If $A$ is a closed subset of a metric space $X$, show that any map 
$f : A → \mathbb{E}^n$ can be extended over X.

Solution:

Let $p_i$ be the projection onto the i-th coordinate. Each $p_i$
is continuous because the inverse of an open interval is clearly open.
Let $f_i = p_i \circ f.$

Each $f_i$ can be extended to a map $g_i: X \rightarrow \mathbb{E}$.

Then $g = (g_1, . . . , g_n)$ extends $f$.

We must show $g$ is continuous.

The sets $I_1 × · · · × I_n$, where $I_i$ are open intervals, form a base for the topology on $\mathbb{E}^n$.

And $$g^{−1}(I_1 × · · · × I_n) = g^{−1}_{1}(I_1) \cap · · · \cap g^{−1}_{n}(I_n)$$

, which is therefore open."

---

I dont understand why this last equality implies that the inverse image is open?

Comment: Can you define the domain and codomain of $g$. What are the hypothesis on the $g_i$?

Comment: Unless you include the full statement of the problem, we won't be able to answer. Who is $g$? Who are $g_1, \dots, g_n$? Are they the components of $g$?

Comment: Ok, one moment.

Comment: If the $I_i$ are open and the $g_i$ are continuous, then this is a finite intersection of open sets, thus open.

Comment: @Stefan Hamcke...Thanks, another basic question: The theorem says that $f_i$ can be extended to a map $g_i$. And a map is by definition a continuous function. If we know that all the components of g are continuous this does not imply that g itself is continuous?

Comment: Without context, the statement is cleary false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $g_i^{-1}(I_i)$ is open in $X$ because each $g_i:X\to E$ is continuous and each $I_i$ is open in $E.$  And $\prod_{i=1}^nI_i$ is open in $E^n.$ Therefore by the last inequality in the text, $\cap_{i=1}^n g^{-1}I_i$ is open in $X.$ So we have a base $B$ for $E^n$ such that $g^{-1}b$ is open in $X$ for every $b\in B.$ Every open $S$ in $E^n$ is equal to $\cup C$ for some $C\subset B$; therefore $g^{-1}S=\cup_{b\in C}g^{-1}b$ is open in $X.$